# Is there a way to get the number of polygons in a scene?

Tags: object, count, three.js, polygon, scene

With three.js , is there a way to retrieve the polygon count of a scene?
I did a search, but the only results that pop up at related to actual polygons and whether meshes have too many, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe renderer.info.render.faces may be what you're after.

Comment: doesn't seem to provide the polygon count. Even with objects in the scene, it just returns 0.

Comment: Do you have some code or example of what you have in the scene? See [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer.info). Note the stats only update after the renderer has rendered the scene -- perhaps you need that info before the scene has been rendered?

Comment: ah.. I was rendering multiple things, so I had to place it after the render with the correct objects. It works now.

Comment: renderer.info no longer has a member 'faces' go [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.info) to see latest members

Answer (score 3):

[ **Update** ]
On Three.js revision **r100** you would get that data through:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
// Code that loads your geometry here
console.log( renderer.info.render.triangles );
```

This same object has several a lot of data that can give you a hint over your memory leaks, so you might just want to console log the whole renderer object and browse all of its properties!

Comment: `renderer.info.render.triangles` returns `0`in my case. of course, I have a 3D model attached to this renderer. actually, all of the fields are 0.
Is there a way to refresh / re-calc the `info` object?

Comment: I would love to but that's a big project, I don't know how :(
Basically I'm using `glTF Loader` and adding the model to my scene.

Comment: Only works after you rendered the scene at least once. @ranbuch

Comment: @nex no, that's not is. I'm running revision 104 BTW.

Comment: Works now with revision 112